# Linear Algebra and Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a (square, $n\times n$) matrix such that
$$ A^T A = I$$
 and $|A|\lt 0$.

Then what can be said about the value of $|A+I|$?  Can we find that value?

Comment: $A$ is orthogonal, so its eigenvalues $\{\lambda_{i}\}$ are all $1$'s and $-1$'s. Since $det(A)<0$, it has at least at least one eigenvalue equal to $-1$ (or an odd number of them). And so $A+I$ (which has eigenvalues $\lambda_{i}+1$) has determinant zero.

Comment: @nemo the determinant of a matrix is the product of all its **complex** roots. You cannot say anything about the complex roots of an orthogonal matrix, except that they have modulus $1$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Okay, the argument won't go through in that case. The question then is, for $\lambda_{i}$ potentially complex with $\Pi_{i}\lambda_{i}<0$, what can be said about $\Pi_{i}(\lambda_{i}+1)$..